# something with sequence.

Tags: real-analysis

For two real number convergent sequence $(X_n), (Y_n)$,  $\lim X_n=x,\lim Y_n=y$ and $x \lt y$, then is it true or false to say that there exist a number $N \in \Bbb N$ such that for any $n \gt N, X_n \lt Y_n?$ Can anybody give me a detailed proof? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is true: Choose $\epsilon = \frac{y - x}{2}$ and consider an $N$ large enough that $|y_n - y| < \epsilon$ and $|x_n - x| < \epsilon$ whenever $n \ge N$.